# How to speed up this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT col1, col2 FROM t WHERE col1 REGEXP '^foobar_[0-9]{4}$';
+----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      |        t      | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 757000 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.15 sec)

mysql> DESCRIBE t;
+------------------------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type                   | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| col2                   | varchar(255)           | NO   | MUL | {}      |       | 
| col1                   | varbinary(255)         | NO   | PRI |         |       | 
+------------------------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.22 sec)
```

Comment: You could try adding a index to col1. However I am not sure if mysql can use a index when performing a regular expression on a column.

Comment: Is NOT `PRI` already a type of index?

Comment: "SHOW CREATE TABLE :tablename" says alot more then "DESCRIBE :tablename"

Comment: Not a lot. Just `ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci`.

Comment: Also, why you add `:` in your query?

Comment: "SHOW CREATE TABLE" also show information about index and constrains, if there is any, and word starting with : is common used for pars of sql that going to be replaced whit real data later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have a index on col1, and add a `LIKE` like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM t 
WHERE col1 LIKE 'foobar_%' AND col1 REGEXP '^foobar_[0-9]{4}$';
```

you should get abit more speed.

you can also make an index of (col1, col2) to make mysql store a copy of that table in memeory

Answer (score 0):

You could speed up this query with creating a third row where you already precalculate the RegEx if its always the same.

MySQL doesn't seem to support [function based indexes](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=4990).